# Custom view of Limit Line in MPAndroidChart Barchart

Tags: android

Is it possible to replace LimitLine with custom layout? So it looks something like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQk8E.png)

```
LimitLine ll1 = new LimitLine(150f, "Upper Limit");
ll1.setLineWidth(4f);
ll1.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
ll1.setLabelPosition(LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT_TOP);
ll1.setTextSize(10f);
ll1.setTypeface(tf);
YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.removeAllLimitLines(); // reset all limit lines to avoid overlapping lines
leftAxis.addLimitLine(ll1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but it will probably help others, as of now I do not know if you can implement custom limitlines, however you have an option to user a custom markerview.

You need to customize TextView, so create .xml file: **custom_marker_view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/oval_marker">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Create class: **MyMarkerView**

```
public class MyMarkerView extends MarkerView {

    private TextView tvContent;

    public MyMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource) {
        super(context, layoutResource);

        tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
    }

    // callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
    // content (user-interface)
    @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
        tvContent.setText(String.format("%.5f", e.getY()));
        super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, float posX, float posY) {
        super.draw(canvas,   (posX + getWidth()) * 100, posY - getHeight() / 2);
    }
}
```

Then in the activity where your chart is: define your markerview and set it

```
MyMarkerView mv = new MyMarkerView(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custom_marker_view);
mv.setChartView(mChart);
mChart.setMarker(mv);
```

Then to specify the coordinate or point to highlight use:

```
mChart.highlightValue(set1.getEntryCount() - 1, my_value, 0);
```

where **my_value** is the y-axis value you want to highlight and and **set1.getEntryCount()** is the x-axis point. Thus to make a coordinate (x,y) where a value will be highlighted.

This gives you exactly your image above, assuming you make small adjustments in the **MyMarkerView.class**.

also if you want only the horizontal line without vertical line use this below:

```
set1.setDrawVerticalHighlightIndicator(false);
set1.setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(true);
set1.setHighlightEnabled(true);
```

and a bonus: highlight line color:

```
set1.setHighLightColor(Color.parseColor("#27ED06"));
```